# Surface integral in Regge-Teitelboim paper

Tags: general-relativity, energy, hamiltonian-formalism

Recently i'm trying to read Regge-Teitelboim paper (Role of surface integrals in the Hamiltonian formulation of general relativity) in order to understand the definition of energy and momentum in GR. Equation (2.6) gives the boundary terms for variating hamiltonian $H_0= \int d^3x \{N {\cal H} + N^i {\cal H}_i\}$ with respect to $g_{ij}$ and $\pi^{ij}$. After some calculations i always end up with factor $1/\sqrt{g}$ for all surface terms in there. Here is my calculation : for example the first surface term in (2.6)

with 
\begin{equation}
{\cal H} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}(\pi_{ij} \pi^{ij} - \frac{1}{2}\pi^2) - \sqrt{g} R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
{\cal H}_i = -2\pi_{i/j}^j = -2 \nabla_j \pi^j_i 
\end{equation}
the variation of $\cal H$ that gives surface terms is the term $-\sqrt{g} \ \delta R$. So by
\begin{equation}
\delta R = \delta g^{ij}  R_{ij} + g^{ij} \delta R_{ij} = bulk + g^{ij} \delta R_{ij} 
\end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
-\sqrt{g}\delta R &=& -\sqrt{g} g^{ij} \delta R_{ij} =  - \sqrt{g} \ \nabla_l \Big( (g^{il}g^{kj} - g^{kl}g^{ij} ) \nabla_k\delta g_{ij} \Big) \\
&=& - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{g} \ \nabla_l \Big( (g^{ik} g^{jl}+g^{il}g^{kj} - 2g^{kl}g^{ij} ) \nabla_k\delta g_{ij} \Big)
\end{eqnarray}
so when we integrate
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d^3x N \delta{\cal H} &=& bulk - \int d^3x \frac{1}{2}N \sqrt{g} \ \nabla_l \Big( (g^{ik} g^{jl}+g^{il}g^{kj} - 2g^{kl}g^{ij} ) \nabla_k\delta g_{ij} \Big) \\
&=& bulk - \int d^3x \sqrt{g} \ \nabla_l \Big( \frac{1}{2}N (g^{ik} g^{jl}+g^{il}g^{kj} - 2g^{kl}g^{ij} ) \nabla_k\delta g_{ij} \Big) + \text{$2^{nd}$ surface term} \\
&=& bulk - \oint d^2s_l \ \frac{N}{\sqrt{g}} G^{ijkl} \nabla_k\delta g_{ij} + \text{$2^{nd}$ surface term} 
\end{eqnarray} 
which is precisely the first surface term in (2.6) but additional factor $g^{-1/2}$ because the definition of $G^{ijkl}$

\begin{equation}
 G^{ijkl} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{g} (g^{ik} g^{jl}+g^{il}g^{kj} - 2g^{kl}g^{ij})
\end{equation}

I always end up like this for all surface term derived in that paper. Anyone know whats wrong here ?

Comment: im sorry. im forget to mention it. Its this Role of surface integrals in the Hamiltonian formulation of general relativity 1974
www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491674904047

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(74)90404-7

Comment: I think this is because in their paper $d^2s_l=r_l\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ with $r_l=\nabla_lr$ if at the boundary (not necessarily infinitely far away) the spatial coordinates can be the Cartesian and $r_l$ is not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\frac{1}{2} N(...) \nabla_k\delta g_{ij}$ as $v^l$. We have $\nabla_l v^l = \partial_l v^l + \Gamma_{li}^l v^i$ and $\int d^3x \sqrt{g} \nabla_l v^l = \int d^3x \sqrt{g} \partial_l v^l +$ bulk $=\int d^3 x \partial_l (\sqrt{g} v^l) +$bulk $= \int d^2 s_l \sqrt{g}v^l +$bulk